# Balancing other atoms in a redox reaction using half reaction method

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox

I have this balanced redox reaction:
$$\ce{2H2O + 8Al + 3NaNO3 + 5NaOH -> 3NH3 + 8NaAlO2}$$
I think its unbalanced form should be (I guess water added to balanced it)
$$\ce{Al + NaNO3 + NaOH -> NH3 + NaAlO2}$$
I wrote the half reactions as
$$
\begin{align}
\ce {6H2O + 8e- + NO3- &-> NH3 + 9OH-}\label{rxn:1}\tag{1}\\
\ce {Al &-> Al^3+ + 3e-}\label{rxn:2}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Then by $3\cdot\eqref{rxn:1} + 8\cdot\eqref{rxn:2}$, final half reaction is:
$$\ce{18H2O + 3NO3- + 8Al -> 3NH3 + 27OH- + 8Al^3+}$$

Now I am really confused how to get above balanced redox reaction by the final half reaction I have obtained. What is the missing idea?

$$\ce{UPDATE:- Anybody please show me how to proceed from here,}$$
$$\ce{18H2O + 3NO3- + 8Al -> 3NH3 + 27OH- + 8Al^3+}$$
$$\ce{to here}$$
$$\ce{2H2O + 8Al + 3NaNO3 + 5NaOH -> 3NH3 + 8NaAlO2}$$

Comment: What you call "final half reaction" is **not** a half; in fact it is a complete reaction, balanced and consistent. It is just that you don't want ions on either side, so you add counterions to them. Also, note that $\ce{Al^3+}$  reacts with $\ce{OH-}$.

Comment: @IvanNeretin yes. Thanks for correction. How to get NaAlO2 as aproduct by doing so? Could you please show the procedure?

Comment: What procedure? Add as much $\ce{OH-}$ as it takes. Remove the water.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I think you didn't get what I said. So from the final reaction that I have, I don't see any obvious way to get the firstly I mentioned FULLY BALANCED reaction with all compounds (Not as IONS) . NO3- become NaNO3 and NH3 remain as same. no problem there. But how Al3+ become NaAlO2? What procedure to get that final complete reaction after having the reaction (with ions)

Comment: You are supposed to "add" the reaction between Al3+ and OH-, which is also known in its own right (say, as AlCl3 + NaOH), not necessarily related to any redox. Can you balance it?

Comment: @IvanNeretin Yes. I can understand balancing of $$\ce{Al^3+ + 3OH- -> Al(OH)3}$$ Then is this right? $$\ce{18H2O + 3NO3- + 8Al -> 3NH3 + 3OH- + 8Al(OH)3}$$ How does that  18H2O  become 2H2O as in the first reaction??

Comment: I guess you've heard about the amphoteric species, didn't you? What will happen with that precipitate of Al(OH)3 if you add more NaOH?

Comment: @IvanNeretin YES! Thank you sir for showing me the way to tackle the question rather than giving the right out answer. I got it. Al(OH)3 + NaOH → Na[Al(OH)4] So it means my balancing was right but I needed to understand what happens to the products if they ALSO mutually react. Am I right? If so I understood. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's about right.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I understood that the products mutually react so, finally I got the reaction, $$\ce{18H2O + 3NO3- + 8Al-> 3NH3 + 5Al(OH)3 + 3Al[(OH)4]-}$$ BUT still, I see no way to get the fully balanced reaction. Could you please kindly post a 'stepwise procedure' as answer to show,$$\ce{how 18 H2O become 2H2O on left side?}$$ $$\ce{how 5Al(OH)3 on right side disappear and 5NaOH appear on left side? }$$ I could balance the other reactions I tried but this one got me stuck really bad.

Comment: Add more OH- to the left so that **all** Al ends up in the anions.

Comment: Wait, something is wrong here. You half reaction has $\ce{Al^{3+}}$ but your total reaction has $\ce{AlO_{2}-}$. You can't go from one directly to the other. Ideally, you have find a half reactions that contain _all_ of the species in the total reaction. Otherwise, you need to do some manipulation.

Comment: @Zhe I'm really confused with this reaction. Could you please tell me a stepwise procedure to balance the reaction(top of page) using method of half reactions?

Comment: If it's reasonably straightforward, I would start by removing all spectator ions. Then you'll notice that your oxidation half reaction has to include something of the form: $\ce{Al -> AlO_{2}-}$. If you don't see that half reaction, you might not have the correct half reactions to do this decomposition...

Comment: @Zhe Man seriously, how would I missed that! Yes it worked like charm. I was messing the whole time with $$\ce{Al  ->Al^3+ + 3e}$$ Please post as answer I'll definitely select it. In your answer, if possible please mention why Al oxidizes to AlO2- instead of Al3+ Thank you so much BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your total reaction is:

$$\ce{2H2O + 8Al + 3NaNO3 + 5NaOH⟶3NH3 + 8NaAlO2}$$

But your choice of oxidation half reaction is:

$$\ce{Al -> Al^{3+} + 3e-}$$

Notice that the right side of the half reaction doesn't represent the right side of the total reaction (once you've accounted for the sodium spectator ion).

You *must* find the corresponding oxidation half reaction, and if it's not available, then you're out of luck.

Your half reaction will have $\ce{Al}$ on the left, and $\ce{AlO2-}$ and 3 electrons on the right; with water, hydrogen ions, and hydroxides to balance.

In comments, you also asked for why this is the oxidation product. That is the wrong question to ask. All you're doing is breaking down the total reaction into component half reactions. The simple half reaction ($\ce{Al|Al^{3+}}$) is totally valid. It's just gives a different total reaction from the one you started with. There's nothing wrong with that reaction. It's just different.

Comment: so you mean I cannot "guess" the reaction products by considering the medium and reactants etc? Does that mean i have to remember the products (by heart)? This is a question for me.

Comment: You can. You just might be wrong. The reaction will do what it wants to do, not what we would like it to do. With appropriate experience and insight, you might have a pretty good success rate, but again, you're just never guaranteed to be right.

Comment: The idea of matching the left & right of half reactions with that of the full reaction to be balanced was something I should've focused. Thanks for pointing that out. Great help and thank you very much sir!